# How to compare the two array items and replace,And also move to particular position

Tags: javascript, arrays

The following is the code for an employee array that contains type, code, and description.
There is also another array called days that contains different time periods.

I need to compare days with employeeArr.

If `day[0] === employeeArr[0].codeDescription`, then do not move and if it is !== then it will replace .
so here if days[1] is weekly then employeeArr[4].codeDescription move to first position.
if day[3] is Quartely then employeeArr[1].codeDescription move to 3rd position.

```js
let employeeArr = [
  { "empType": "da", "empCode": "1", "codeDescription": "Daily" },
  { "empType": "hy", "empCode": "6", "codeDescription": "Quarterly" },
  { "empType": "mo", "empCode": "4", "codeDescription": "Monthly" },
  { "empType": "qu", "empCode": "5", "codeDescription": "Half Yearly" },
  { "empType": "wl", "empCode": "2", "codeDescription": "Weekly" },
  
]

let days = ["Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly", "Quartely", "Half Yearly"];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the result by making a map of days with employees

```
let employeeMap =employeeArr.reduce((rs,el) => {let currentKey = el['codeDescription']; let currentObj = {}; currentObj[currentKey.toString()]=el;return Object.assign(rs, currentObj)}, {})
var result = days.map(el =>employeeMap[el])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Here the output got the wrong on last two object ?
Could you please check and let me know onto the third index I got undefined and on fourth I got the 3rd one.
Thanks.

Comment: You got a typo here I guess `let days = ["Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly", "Quartely", "Half Yearly"];` It should be `let days = ["Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly", "Quarterly", "Half Yearly"];`

Comment: One more question , employeeArr  is the dynamic ,In some cases employeeArr  contains only 3 objects into that case I got undefined.

Comment: yeah, so you just remove undefined element from that result then you have the ordered array

Answer (score 0):

```js
let employeeArr = [
  { "empType": "da", "empCode": "1", "codeDescription": "Daily" },
  { "empType": "hy", "empCode": "6", "codeDescription": "Quarterly" },
  { "empType": "mo", "empCode": "4", "codeDescription": "Monthly" },
  { "empType": "qu", "empCode": "5", "codeDescription": "Half Yearly" },
  { "empType": "wl", "empCode": "2", "codeDescription": "Weekly" },
]

let days = ["Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly", "Quarterly", "Half Yearly"];


let modEmployee = []
var i, j;
for (i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < employeeArr.length; j++) {
    if (employeeArr[j].codeDescription === days[i]) {
      modEmployee.splice(i, 0, employeeArr[j]);
    }
  }
}

console.log(modEmployee);
```

Output:

```
[ { empType: 'da', empCode: '1', codeDescription: 'Daily' },
  { empType: 'wl', empCode: '2', codeDescription: 'Weekly' },
  { empType: 'mo', empCode: '4', codeDescription: 'Monthly' },
  { empType: 'hy', empCode: '6', codeDescription: 'Quarterly' },
  { empType: 'qu', empCode: '5', codeDescription: 'Half Yearly' } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a compare function like this

```js
const comparator = (emp1, emp2) => {
    const days = ["Daily", "Weekly", "Monthly", "Quarterly", "Half Yearly"];
    return days.indexOf(emp1.codeDescription) - days.indexOf(emp2.codeDescription);
};
```

And then use it to sort the `employeeArr`

```js
employeeArr.sort(comparator);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in O(n) using HashMap.

```
   Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        //Iterate employee array and store the description as key and index as value in map
        for(int i=0;i<employeeArr.length;i++)
        {
            Employee e =  employeeArr[i];
            map.put(e.description,i);
        }

        //Iterate days array, find the corresponding position in map, swao the indexing position in map and swap the values in Employee array if it is not in expected order
        for(int j=0;j<days.length;j++)
        {
            int index = map.get(days[j]);
            if(index == j)
            {
                continue;
            }
            Employee temp = employeeArr[index];
            employeeArr[index] = employeeArr[j];
            employeeArr[j] = temp;
            map.put(employeeArr[index].description, index);
            map.put(employeeArr[j].description, j);
        }
```